# How to programmatically click on a text input using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I'm trying to implement a messaging application in my game, so instead of clicking on the input text field manually, I want users to only press "enter", write something, then press "enter" again to submit.

For some reason, when I do this (press "enter"), the `onclick` alert fires from the input, but the input stays the same, I am still not able to type into the input form. If I manually click it, it works fine.

Am I missing something?

**HTML**

```
<form id="messageInput" action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" onclick="alert('clicked')"/>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
if(keyOn["enter"]){
    keyOn["enter"] = false;

    $('#m').click();

    console.log("clicked");
}
```

Comment: i am removing jquery tag in here as you wanted pure js on this

Comment: Jquery is preferable, I should include in title

Comment: @tery.blargh check the solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, but I somehow found the solution by randomly checking everything I saw:

```
$("#m").trigger("focus");
```

Use `focus` instead of `click`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#m').click(function() {

  alert("click")
}).click();//click here to click automatically on load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="messageInput" action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" />
</form>
```

Using jquery you can call `.click()`

Comment: Same thing, alert opens up, but the input text field is not clicked

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written is for capturing the click event (`$("#m").click()`).
Try:

```
$("#m").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Alert pops up, but still not clicked, feels like same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..press enter.Event will trigger.

```js
if(confirm('Are you want submit message?')){
$("#m").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
       alert('clicked');
       $("#m").val('');
    }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="messageInput" action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" />
</form>
```

Comment: This didn't work at all, alert didn't fire either, even including `$("#m").val('');`

Comment: Thank you for the help but, I found working solution

Comment: @tery.blargh best of luck ahead.if answer is good one feel free to tick mark.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in an Angular app where the "click" would fire and open something from the element but it wouldn't do any of the angular method calls I had defined in (click)="...", I also found it wouldn't fire off anything defined in onclick()

The solution for me was to add .get(0)

```
$(el).get(0).click();
```